# Dependency injection of service not working

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular8

Hi i am beginner in angular and i tried to follow a tutorial. i tried everything but my dependency injection is not working. It is working when i directly put the EVENTS on event-list component.

Here is the code.

event-list component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from './shared/events.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'events-list',
    template: `<div>
    <h1>Upcoming Angular Events</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="let event of events" class="col-md-5">
            <event-thumbnail  [event]="event">
            </event-thumbnail>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
`
})

export class EventsListComponent {
    events: any[]

    constructor(private eventService: EventService) {    
        this.events = this.eventService.getEvents()
    }

   // ngOnInit() {
   //    this.events = this.eventService.getEvents()
   // }
}
```

event-service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()

export class EventService {

    getEvents() {

        return EVENTS
    }
}

const EVENTS = [
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

app-module

```
import { EventService } from './events/shared/events.service';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    RootAppComponent,
    EventsListComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    EventThumbnailComponent
  ],
  providers: [EventService],
  bootstrap: [RootAppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I tried its working..

Answer (score 0):

Could you try rewrite your service this way:

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventService {
...
}
```

After this you can remove EventService from your AppModule's providers list. Try this and if this not solve your problem feel free to ask.
Edit: And I can recommend you to write `this.events = this.eventService.getEvents()` in `ngOnInit()` not in constructor.

Comment: Hello, i actually already tried that and it is still not working, also it does not have errors

Comment: Could you declare some public value and console that in your component for testing: f.e. public test = 5 in your service and console.log(this.eventService.test) in your component's ngOnInit() hook. To be sure that DI not working (or working).

Comment: everything inside constructor and nginit is not getting hit by breakpoint in dev tools. console.log also not getting called inside them

Comment: Are you sure you call your component?